# Passing a dropdown list selected value to a detail view in a different page?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a table with employee info: email, name , address etc. On one page a have a drop down with only the emails (Primary key) and on the second page I'd like to display a detail view for each employee. So far I've assigned the selected email to a session value.

```
    Dim SelectedEmail As String

     SelectedEmail = DropDownList1.SelectedValue
Session("selection") = SelectedEmail
```

I created a button in the first page that takes me to the detail page and viceversa. I'm having issues retrieving the email, so far i only have this:

Dim selectedemail As String = Session("selection")

Comment: This may help you: http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/blogs/haissam/archive/2007/11/26/ways-to-pass-data-between-webforms.aspx

Comment: What happens if you have two tabs open on your site? Your session variables will start colliding and result in weird behavior. Usually if you want to pass an ID or simple value to another page, you use query string or URL segments.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a stab.

It appears that all you've done is put the selected value in a local variable

```
Dim SelectedEmail As String
SelectedEmail = DropDownList1.SelectedValue
```

when I think your intention is to put it in a session variable

```
Session("selection") = DropDownList1.SelectedValue
```

So that you can pick it up again on the other page

```
Dim selectedEmail As String = Session("selection")
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the issue but it is working fine in my case.

I have added a button and a dropdownlist in a page called default.aspx

```
 <li class="three">
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
 </li>
```

In the Page.Load event handler I put three ListItem in the dropDownlist and in the Button.Click event handler I added a session attribute with the selectedValue from the DropDownList

Here is the code

```
 Public Class _Default
Inherits Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim item1 As ListItem = New ListItem("Test A", "test A", True)
    Dim item2 As ListItem = New ListItem("Test AB", "test AB", True)
    Dim item3 As ListItem = New ListItem("Test C", "test C", True)


    DropDownList1.Items.Add(item1)
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(item2)
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(item3)


End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Session("variable") = "Test value"
    Session("thevalue") = DropDownList1.SelectedValue


    Response.Redirect("default2.aspx")

End Sub
```

End Class

When the click on the button occurs I provide the SelectedValue to Session("theValue") and redirect to default2.aspx. In default2.aspx I just use the Page.Load event to write on the Response stream after retrieving the Session attribute:

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim myvariable As String = Session("variable")
    Response.Write("the found value is" + myvariable)
    Dim theValue As String = Session("thevalue")
    Response.Write("<Br/> from drop down =" + theValue)



End Sub
```

It's working just fine.

For example when I select the 2nd item from the DropDownlist I have the following result

the found value isTest value

from drop down =test AB

So the issue lies somewhere else. You may check and see if you are handling the IsPostBack correctly in the Page.Load event. If you could share more of your code, that would help.

Comment: thanks for your comment.. however my dropdown list is using values from an access table . Im using one field (email) from the table to populate the dropdown list and all the fields for the detail view. so what i need to do is save the selected email into a session variable (?) and somehow match it in the detail view in page 2